# JOptionPane chamando a tela Main

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Boa noite , acredito que está dúvida seja simples mas não consigo resolver, tenho um método que exibe uma mensagem instruindo o usuário no preenchimento de um Captcha, até ai ok, o "problema" é que quando pressiono OK nesse JDialog ele automaticamente abre a minha tela principal que está em outro pacote.

```
private static boolean telaCaptcha() {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Digite o código abaixo e clique em 'Solicitar Certidão' aguarde retorno da consulta, pressione OK nesta janela e o processo seguinte será automatizado");
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("ATENÇÃO!");

        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        return tela = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para exibir um `jop` não é preciso instancia-lo, basta escrever

```java
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite o código abaixo e clique em 'Solicitar Certidão' aguarde retorno da consulta, pressione OK nesta janela e o processo seguinte será automatizado", "Atenção", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Outro detalhe que pode te ajudar é instanciar um jDialog no seu frame principal.

o JDialog vai pausar a execução do seu frame, até q o próprio jdialog receba algum evento de fechamento (ex: dispose()), então vai retornar pro seu frame.

No Netbeans tem a opção de criar um jDialog (lá aonde vai pra criar classes etc..) e esse dialog vem ja com todos os eventos e tudo mais criado, facilitando bastante a manipulação do mesmo. Ele é como um frame, pode ser feito verificações e tudo mais dentro dele (pois é uma classe como todas as outras coisas), isso pode ser util já que pelo que entendi você precisa abrir esse jdialog para o usuário preencher uma captcha, e então se acertado retornar ao frame principal (eu acho que é isso).

além disso dentro do próprio jDialog você poderia criar metodos get para receber no frame caso o usuário opte por fechar o dialog sem concluir o captcha..

algo como..

```java
CaptchaDialog cap = new CaptchaDialog(null,true);
cap.setVisible(true);
if (!cap.getValidacao){
   //o usuario optou por fechar o dialog sem conluir o captcha
}else{
  //o usuario acertou o captcha
}
```

Comment: Só fiz criando o dialog pois precisavado método setAlwaysOnTop que não é aplicável no JOptionPane.